# Why does the evaluation of "Catch[Break[],\$Failed]" not return "\$Failed"?

Tags: function-construction

Under *normal* conditions, evaluating something that emits a `Message` eg the evaluation of

```
1/0
```

that produces a `Message` `Power::infy` with text

> *Power: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered.*

can be dealt with an expression like

```
Quiet[Check[1/0, $Failed]]
```

which returns `$Failed` and invokes no `Message`.

When evaluating `Break[]` '*naked*' (outside any flow control loop) the front end issues a message `Break::nofwd` with a text

> *Break: No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[]*

and returns

```
Hold[Break[]]
```

I was expecting that after evaluating

```
Quiet[Check[Break[],$Failed]]
```

I'd obtain `$Failed` (without any messages generated in the process).

Instead, I get the same message `Break::nofwd` as before *and* the same output as before ie `Hold[Break[]]`.

It is as if `Check` doesn't do anything when `Break` is its first argument.

**Could someone please explain why I get this counter-intuitive result?**

PS. I'm trying to pass `Break[]` or a function that has `Break[]` in its body as an argument to another function with a `While` loop in its body. The former function would ideally force the later function to exit the loop without any messages.

```
f[___]:=Break[]
SetAttributes[g, HoldAll]
g[func_] := Module[{res = Quiet[Check[func, $Failed]], j = 0},
  While[
    FailureQ[res] && j < 10,
    res = Quiet[Check[func, $Failed]];
    j++
  ];
  j
 ]
```

Evaluating `g[f[]]` returns the familiar `Break::nofwd` and returns `Hold[Break[]]`; I understand that this happens because `res = Quiet[Check[func, $Failed]]` gets evaluated during the initialization of `Module`.

Comment: Apparently, `Break` is a version of local `Goto`, and when there is no enclosing construct that stops it, it bubbles up, just like exceptions or aborts, except it is neither of those, so can't be caught using any of the `Catch`, `Check`, etc. So it would probably need a separate `Check`-like function, like e.g. this: `SetAttributes[checkBreak, HoldFirst]; checkBreak[code_, failExpr_] := Module[{breakUsed = True, result}, Do[result = code; breakUsed = False,  {1}]; If[breakUsed, failExpr, result]]`.

Comment: Why does the function have to contain `Break[]`? If it is to force breaking the loop, then `f` could just return `$Failed` and you could just check `res` right before `j++` using `If[FailureQ[res],Break[]]`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you! Am I correct to infer that `Do` can be replaced with any other built-in that breaks with `Break[]`?

Comment: @Hector I understand your point; in the current example what you're suggesting is actually the case! but this is just a toy example of my production code; `f` is a stand-in for code that uses `Import` to scrape html content and sometimes it returns error messages

Comment: @user42582 Yes, can also use `For` or `While` etc. in appropriate form. I used `Do` since it is simple and I can easily ensure that the code is executed exactly once. In general, the need for such a construct is rather weird - I never needed that.  But the observation itself, that `Break[]` and `Continue` represent another type of signals,  is important.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thank you! I understand what you're saying; I'll try to refactor my code-probably-along the lines of *@Hector*'s suggestion or something similar